# Creaking whilst pedaling (BB)?

Tags: bottom-bracket, creak

I am having this creaking issue for months now it happens whilst pedaling and gets worse with more force.

I've checked the headset, the handlebars as well as re-greasing and reinstalling the pedals and check torque on cranks. Now I am afraid that it would be the bottom bracket that went bust.

I noticed that there is a slight creak when i compress the front brakes and press on the pedals with my legs. coming from the BB area (Bike is not in motion) Could it be the bottom bracket?

FYI: I have done 2500 km on the bike when I bought it used. and this is an alu frame if it helps. shimano rs500 threaded BB.

EDIT: I might have fixed it. Culprit is the derailleur hanger rubbing with the grit and grime with the frame. Regreased it and seems like no creaking when i step on the pedals hard :D

Comment: Does it happen when not sitting on the saddle?

Comment: @VladimirF yes it does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. rear derailleur hanger is the culprit.